# HTML5 Audio events not triggering on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events, html5-audio

I'm trying to have a load progress bar in my game, and I have a function assigned to the `onloadeddata` attribute on my audio, but it is not triggering in Chrome. It works in other browsers. I also tried many other events such as `oncanplay`, `oncanplaythrough`, `onloadedmetadata`, etc. None of them trigger.

I think it might have to do with the caching. Tried looking around and there was some reports of this from 2-3 years ago but nothing recent.

Is there any other way I could detect if the audio is loaded, or make these events work?

EDIT: Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vxCu/1/
Works in Opera and Firefox, but not in Chrome. It should give an alert when sound if finished loading.

Comment: Could you please share your javascript code where you are loading the audio files and attaching the event listeners?

Comment: @pseudosavant Added example on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the `onloadeddata` property does not work for some reason. But attaching an event handler through `addEventListener` (or via jQuery) works: http://jsfiddle.net/3vxCu/4/

```
bgSound = new Audio();
bgSound.src = "http://www.ehsankia.com/hawkthorne/audio/level.ogg";
bgSound.preload = "auto";
// Standard browsers (not IE before version 9):
// bgSound.addEventListener("loadeddata", testFunction, false);

// jQuery:
$(bgSound).on("loadeddata", testFunction);

function testFunction () {
    alert("Data loaded");
}
```

Comment: Strange. I'm no professional but seems like a Chrome bug to me. Someone should submit a ticket or something.

Yours works great though, thanks!

Comment: @EhsanKia You've tested this issue most thoroughly, why don't you write the bug report? :) http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 3):

If the attached jsfiddle is how you have implemented your code then I think I know what is wrong.

Your jsfiddle shows:

```
bgSound = document.createElement('audio');
bgSound.src = "http://www.ehsankia.com/hawkthorne/audio/level.ogg";
bgSound.onloadeddata = testFunction;

function testFunction(){
    alert("Data loaded");
}
```

It should be like this:

```
bgSound = document.createElement('audio');
bgSound.onloadeddata = testFunction; // Event listener is attached _before_ loading the resource
bgSound.src = "http://www.ehsankia.com/hawkthorne/audio/level.ogg";

function testFunction(){
    alert("Data loaded");
}
```

Basically, you are attaching the event listener *after* the `src` is specified. Specifying the source should be the last thing you do since it sets everything in motion. Chrome is probably already past the point of calling listeners for that event by the time it is attached in your code.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Data is loaded asynchronously and I think even if the data is already cached the event handlers are called asynchronously (i.e. after the currently running JavaScript finished). However, I think IE does sometimes handle such things synchronously (at least it once called a `onhashchange` handler synchronously for me, while all other browsers call it asynchronously).

Comment: I can tell you with 100% certainty that you should *always* set your event listeners before you set your `src` property. You are assuming asynchronous means that things are always run out of sequence, but that isn't always the case. The only way you can be 100% sure that your event listener is attached before the event(s) get call is to attach them before you set the `src`. Chrome takes a lot of shortcuts/optimizations to be fast and it might not even try to call events when `src` is set if nothing is listening for any.