# audio.onloaded with function

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I guess this is a stupid question, but I just cannot crack this.

When I call

```
audio.onloadeddata = function(){
    alert('hello');
}
```

it doesn't work but when I call

```
audio.onloadeddata = alert('hello');
```

It does work. ALso on other websites about audio tags they use the same syntax as me wit function, so why it doesn't work for me ?

I am getting a little bit desperate here...

------------ Adding the full function -------------

```
jQuery('.btn-play-single').click(function(){
    var statusTemp = jQuery('#statusTemp');
    var button = jQuery(this);
    var loader = jQuery('.ajax-loader',jQuery(this).parent());
    var el = document.getElementById('record'+jQuery(this).attr('alt'));

    if (el.paused){
        statusTemp.append('<div>Sound is paused and i will play it</div>');
        button.hide();
        loader.show();

        el.onloadeddata = function(){
            statusTemp.append('<div>Sound has loaded and Im changing buttons</div>');
            button.css({backgroundPosition:'0px -40px'});
            loader.hide();
            button.show();
            el.play();
        };

        el.onended = function(){
            statusTemp.append('<div>Sound has finished and changing buttons back</div>');
            button.css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
        };

    } else {
        button.css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
        el.pause();
        el.currentTime = 0;
        statusTemp.append('<div>Sound was playing and I stopped it</div>');
    }

});
```

Comment: Has the data already been loaded when you attach the handler? `audio.onloadeddata = alert('hello');` is same as saying `alert('hello'); audio.onloadeddata = undefined;`

Comment: @Esailija I have added the full function.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790091/html5-audio-events-not-triggering-on-chrome