# audio.js isn't run when using chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

This is the first time I use audio.js

Shortly [here](http://www.yabspor.com/mixtape/id/1) is the page. When using firefox there isn't any problem. But when using chrome getting this error.

> Error loading: "http://www.yabspor.com/musics/yabspor1.mp3

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers do not support mp3s, although the latest version of chrome should.  Try including an option for .ogg and see if that fixes it (note that you'll also need to provide a  .ogg version of the song in the same directory):

```
<audio src="http://www.yabspor.com/musics/yabspor1.mp3" preload="auto">
<audio src="http://www.yabspor.com/musics/yabspor1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
```

If you know that you have a current version of chrome, you might just want to declare the audio type as an mp3:

```
<audio src="http://www.yabspor.com/musics/yabspor1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="auto">
```

You can read a bit more about html5 audio [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: this is not solving my problem. Look plugins main page it doesn't run, too. http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/

Comment: lol, well, if their own demo page doesn't even work...  

Seems that this is a [common issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790091/html5-audio-events-not-triggering-on-chrome)

If that link doesn't work, maybe try adding `g[h].helpers.removeClass(this.wrapper, b.errorClass);` to the loadStarted function in the audio.js file and see what happens.  Since its a load error, that seems like the place to look

Comment: to where? I can't understand.

Comment: Ok, look at the annoated source [on the github page](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/docs/), which is easier to follow what the code does.

search for "loadstarted". Within the `loadStarted` function, add this argument: `g[h].helpers.removeClass(this.wrapper, b.errorClass);`

Then replace the original loadStarted function with the updated function in your audio.js file.

If that doesn't work, try and see if the article in the link I posted above is relevant to your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing audiojs on localhost, it will not work correctly with the Flash fallback. This happens if you try to play mp3's in Firefox (or old versions of Chrome). Access your site through IP address instead.